# How I can send logs of crash to my e-mail?

Tags: android, exception

I have looked through all the Internet, and I didn't find any good and working way of sending logs of fatal crash to my e-mail. In general I try to send logs of any crash and I have to find really good way. For example I saw such variant:

```
private void SendLogcatMail(Throwable e) {
        String stackTrace = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"*****@gmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Problem with your application");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, stackTrace);
        try {
            emailIntent.setType("application/octet-stream");
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

where I have to call this method with exception code. I didn't find any good method for handling exceptions and errors and sending them to my mailbox. Maybe someone saw some good variant of solution of my problem. I will be pleased to see it. Thank you !!!

Comment: why don't you use crashlytics ?

Comment: Exactly. Crashlytics is a great way to monitor what is happening in your app.

Comment: what is it? I saw some services but didn't understand how to use it :)

Comment: have a look at [crashlytics page.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra). It's easy to setup.

Looks like this

```
@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "yourmail",
        customReportContent = {
                ReportField.LOGCAT},
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.SILENT,
        resToastText = "Crash Report")
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
```

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko You would do that in your Application class. Look into the github repository for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://fabric.io service. In this case you will automatically receive crashes with logs and all information about device.

Stacktrace will be there.

It is a big service with part like **crashlytics**.

Comment: I saw it, but I didn't understand how to add it to my project

Comment: You should install fabric plugin into the Android Studio and when you will add a project to fabric you will find a simple instruction. In take lass than 5 minutes. Plugin names "Fabric for Android Studio" [https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-crashlytics-for-android-by-fabric-tutorial/] - here a simple tutorial